# Rhombicosidodecahedron Slitherlink

Tags: grid-deduction, three-dimensional, slitherlink

This is a **Slitherlink** puzzle, being played on the surface of a 3D object, a [Rhombicosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicosidodecahedron).  If you are not familiar with Slitherlink puzzles, I don't suggest starting on this one.

Rules in review:

- Goal is to draw a single, non-intersecting, loop along the edges of this object
- Each number clue tells you how many edges of that face are part of the loop
- A face left blank is unknown
- There is exactly one loop that satisfies the clues

I am able to solve this puzzle on a single sheet of paper, which is to say there is no need for any major guess-work.

> [image]

I am interested in constructive feedback on the format of the puzzle.  The top view is the top, the bottom view is the bottom, and the four in the middle are the four side views (all 90 deg apart).  I hope it isn't too confusing... and apologies to the color-blind.

Comment: I saw this got a downvote within one minute... I don't suppose I'll get an explanation?

Comment: I'm sure I've played slitherlink before, but I'm not 100% which of the 100 Nikoli puzzles it is. A rule summary would be nice (even though it's already summarized in the tag excerpt) as well as a few words on how to stitch the RID (even though the coloring admits only one way to stitch). Not sure what else might be considered unclear about this puzzle or even if that is the issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane Fixed!  Sorry!  This was humbling, I'm usually more careful... usually.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, you asked for non-destructive feedback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the picture below, the green line is the unique solution.
When the puzzle was first posed, one clue was missing, which allowed a second solution shown in blue.

> I started with the top face. There is only one way that the 4 can be done due to the adjacent triangle 2 and square 3 clues. Most of the rest would also be straightforward if it were on a physical 3d polyhedron, but it is a bit tricky here because you have to constantly compare the pictures to see what is going on.
>  [image]

Comment: Oh boy.  Yeah that's on me... I'll probably have to add a clue...

Comment: I updated the picture to be the intended path, for what that's worth.  Real sorry about that.  Obviously you'll be getting the checkmark